# how to correct this code with pragma solidity^ 0.5.8? thx

Tags: solidity, truffle

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;


contract HelloWorld {

    function test() pure returns (string) {
        return "HelloWorld";
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the problem with it (perhaps apart from the function not being declared `public`/`private`/`external`/`internal`)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the right compiler version (use a different one if needed) you are missing a few keywords from the function: `public` to denote that the function is accessible everywhere and `memory` to denote that the string is loaded from memory - string parameters have to be loaded from memory.

So the corrected version is:

```
function test() public pure returns (string memory) {
    return "HelloWorld";
}
```

Comment: i am sorry do you know how to correct this code  for the ^0.5.8 compiler  ,                                         
function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns（uint256）{
        return balances[_owner];
    }  thx

Comment: Please post a new question if you have a new problem